# What do I name my inputs when I save a has_many relationship from my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I’m using Rails 5.  I have this model

```
class Scenario < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :grading_rubric, optional: true
  has_many :confidential_memo
  has_many :scenario_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :roles, :through => :scenario_roles
    …
end
```

In my view, I’m dynamically creating the role elements (after a user clicks “Add”).  The elements are created like so …

```
<input size="30" validate="true" type="text" name="scenario[roles][name]" id="scenario_roles_name">
```

All my elements get created in the above way.  When I submit my form, the parameters are submitted as

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n2/51OSHlNP+1E7qnLku/gXtCjUk/MfMxwsrNpUirR2IbQddOzP1/OClL50ClCPvDNIowvdsqpVNmer37Egp4w==", "scenario"=>{"title"=>"title #1", "abstract"=>"abstract", "roles"=>{"name"=>"bbb"}}}
```

The problem is, although my scenario model is saved, the role elements are not saved.  Here is how I’m trying to save them …

```
def create
@scenario = Scenario.new(scenario_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @scenario.save
    puts "saved successfully."
    format.html { redirect_to new_scenario_confidential_memo_path(@scenario), notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
  else
    puts "full messages: #{@scenario.errors.full_messages}"
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  end
end
end

…
def scenario_params
  params.require(:scenario).permit(:title, :abstract, :scenario_roles)
end
```

I feel like I’m not naming my input elements correctly and that’s why the roles aren’t saving.  How do I name my elements so that they save?

Comment: can you please add scenario_role, roles model attributes?

Comment: Try changing the `scenario_params` to   `params.require(:scenario).permit(:title, :abstract, roles: [:name])`

Comment: Chagning scenario_params to that results in getting an "Role(#70140103859440) expected, got Array(#70140096260100)" error when eecuting this line "@scenario = Scenario.new(scenario_params) " in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Pavan, you permitted are a little off.

Whenever I'm having trouble getting data from a form into my models, I do the following every single time:

```
pp params
pp permitted_params
# assignment
pp model
# and in your case
pp model.collection
# save
pp model.errors
```

This usually also helps, because printing the permitted params method also shows what's been blacklisted.

As for:

```
def scenario_params
  params.require(:scenario).permit(:title, :abstract, roles: [:name])
end
```

I would lean towards adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles` to your model, then follow up with these params:

```
def scenario_params
  params.require(:scenario).permit(:title, :abstract, roles_attributes: [:name])
end
```

There are helper methods in Rails to help manage these types of form:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

And here's documentation to understand the ActiveRecord part of this:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

But maybe you don't need to do it like this, I'm not sure.

For an example app in Rails 4.2 of nested association posting and helper methods you can use to generate the structure your looking for:

[example app](https://www.github.com/frank184/surveysays)

Which is based off RailsCasts episode 196 that you can find on the internet:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: K, I edited my scenario_params line to "params.require(:scenario).permit(:title, :abstract, roles_attributes: [:name] )" and added "accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles" to app/models/scenario.rb, but when submitting with the parameters in my question, I get a "Unpermitted parameter: roles" error on the server.

Comment: You need to also change your form to post back the `roles_attributes` instead of `roles` (i.e. change the input `name`).